# Jquery mobile Popup menu not working as desired?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0, popupmenu

i have created a pop up menu in my app.The problem is when i click on the button 1st time it shows the pop-menu  and when i click outside the popup menu menu should be hidden but its not hiding. and when i click on another button the pop menu hides but doesnot open again if i click on the menu button again.
Here is the code written for popup menu:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="demo_page" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>FOOOTER DEMO</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Footerdemo</h1>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d"
                data-divider-theme="d">
                <li><a href="#">Adduser</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AddCompany</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr align="center" height="50">
                <td><a href="#popupMenu" class="btn_add" data-rel="popup"
                    data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="addbtn"
                    data-transition="slideup"></a></td>
                <td><a href="footerdesign.html" class="btn_edit"
                    data-role="button" data-icon="editbtn" data-inline="true"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn_delete" data-role="button"
                    data-icon="deletebtn" data-inline="true" onclick="deleteUser()"></a>
                </td>
                <td><a href="footerdesign.html" class="btn_menu"
                    data-role="button" data-icon="menubtn" data-inline="true"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your jQuery script?

Comment: I didn't used any jQuery script..

Comment: what is not working? Everything is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/7r7Ux/

Comment: yup its working fine in jsfiddle but when try to run in browser or mobile phone or emulator its not working. Even I am confused that why its not working.

Comment: @NeeravShah open the fiddle in mobile, its working fine. You have probably some other issue. Please post the complete code

Comment: Solved it the problem was with the css file still not able to figure out what was the exact problem I just change the css file and its working fine.

Comment: Its working fine but know the problem is when i scroll the page the popup menu is also scroll with it so can any tell me how to avoid it.